# MYSQL: replacing a phonenumber to add a countrycode

Tags: mysql, replace, phone-number

I have a table with phonenumbers that are not correct.
Some have numbers like: 06xxxxxxxx
Others have numbers like: 06-xxxxxxxx
I want them like this: +316xxxxxxxx

My table:
userid, phonenumber, country

My current (non-working query) query:
UPDATE account_number am
SET am.phonenumber = REPLACE(am.phonenumber,'06','+316');

The above will not work, because if someone would have a number like +31611061111
it will also be replaced and become +31611+3161111

I hope my question is not to complicated.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

First, update the numbers starting with **06-**.

```
UPDATE account_number am 
SET am.phonenumber = CONCAT('+316', SUBSTRING(am.phonenumber, 4)) 
WHERE am.phonenumber LIKE '06-%';
```

Then update the ones with starting just **06**. Order of execution is crucial here.

```
UPDATE account_number am 
SET am.phonenumber = CONCAT('+316', SUBSTRING(am.phonenumber, 3)) 
WHERE am.phonenumber LIKE '06%';
```

Comment: This works great, thank you very much..

Tried to use substring but couldnt get it to work properly though.

Thanks again

Comment: I think i have to use:
`UPDATE account_number am 
SET am.phonenumber = REPLACE(am.phonenumber,'-','');`

first because i found more phonenumbers that have '-' elsewhere, and then use the second UPDATE from above.
That should do it

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
UPDATE account_number am
SET am.phonenumber = '+316' + Substring(am.phonenumber,3,Length(am.phonenumber) - 2)
where am.phonnumber like '06%'
```

Comment: I tried this one too, it seems like my mysql client had a hard time with DataLength complaining that it didnt exist

Comment: oops Had my T-sql head on it's length in mysql

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WHERE` clause to match numbers that only start with 06 if that's what you're after. To achieve that use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like)

Comment: That would still stuff up '06906067' etc.

Comment: You would perform update only on numbers that start with 06xxxxxxx. That's my question if that's the only requirement or not. If not please list all your requirements, what numbers should be updated and which ones should not

Comment: 06906067 does start with 06, so without further expansion, you answer would result in +3169+316+3167, which was my point not the OPs...